# To find the missing digits in a long division.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

[image]

It is given that the leading digit of every number in the division structure is nonzero.

I am not getting how to find all the missing digits given only one digit from the quotient and given that the reminder is $0$.

Any help on how to proceed will be helpful.

---

Source: Homework Assignment.

---

This is what I got.

[image]

Comment: Well to things come to mind.  $7\times$ a three digit number is $3$ digit.  That means the first three digit number is small.  In fact it must be less than $150$.  And it means the second is large.  At least $700$.  Secondly and four digit number minus a three digit number is a two digit number.  Due to carrying the for digit number must begin with $1$ and the three with $9$ and the second digit of the $4$ digit number is $0$.  Keep chewing on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most powerful piece of information comes from the 7 in the quotient. If you look down from there, you see that 7 times the three-digit divisor gives a three-digit number. That means that the divisor has to be between 100 and 142 (since 7x143 = 1001), and so its first digit must be 1.

From that, you can see that a couple of the products are 4 digits, so they must be multiplying the divisor by 8 or 9 - but even 142x9 = 1278, so the first of those four digits must be a 1. You can then use that to gain more information about the divisor, and also about what digits could go in each place.